# Create equal column height in mobile version

Tags: css, wordpress

I just created a [classified ads website](https://dijubelinaja.com/) which has some items on the homepage, and i want to make it equal for the column height. It works well on the desktop version, but doesn't work for the mobile. I tried to use `display: grid;` to make it equal, but it doesn't work. Is there any other way how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

you can use *max-heigh* and *min-height* to put some exact limitation for you divisions
something like this:

```css
main{
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background:red;
}

.tstbx{
  width:100px;
  background:yellow;
  max-height:120px;
  min-heigh:120px;
  overflow:scroll;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="tstbx">
  <a>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
</a>
</div>

<div class="tstbx">
  <a>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
</a>
</div>

<div class="tstbx">
  <a>Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.
</a>
</div>
  
</main>
```

Comment: I've tried to use `min-height` and `max-height`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure you set min-height and max-height for the right div?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I tried it one by one, and it looks not proper when I set the min-height and max-height